# keystore tampered with error on Gradle with Intellij

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, build, keystore

I've tried for a long time to build a multi-dependency project using IntelliJ and gradle. The project builds successfully on the command line (bash) with ./gradlew build. However, when I import the project into IntelliJ I keep getting the following build error:

Could not resolve org.junit.jupiter:.....

> Required by:
> Could not resolve org.junit.jupiter..
> >could not get resource '*private company name/lib-release/org/junit....:
> >org.apache.http.ssl.SSLInitializationException: Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect

I've tried:
-looking at my gradle.properties file to look for proxy settings (couldn't find any)

- cleared my gradle cache and refreshed
- cleared the intelliJ cache and refreshed
- tried using the gradle wrapper vs a local installation

What confuses me is that the build seems to work fine from the command line, so I'm not sure where these issues are coming from. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Is the JDK used by IntelliJ and the command line task same ?

Comment: Yes it is! I've set the IntelliJ JDK to point to the environmental variable JAVA_HOME which is used by command line.

Comment: Does it help if you put this to gradle.properties? systemProp.javax.net.ssl.trustStore=/<path_to_java_home>/jre/lib/security/cacerts
systemProp.javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=changeit